# Hide the lines of the municipalities in a map using d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a division of departments (red lines) and municipalities (lines in gray). I would like my map to hide the lines of the municipalities to later use a button to appear or disappear these lines. With opacity: 0 does not work. Another thing I want to achieve is to paint red departments, this includes the outside lines that are not currently painted, I mean the lines of the outline map.

```
  d3.json("https://cdn.rawgit.com/finiterank/mapa-colombia-js/9ae3e4e6/colombia-municipios.json", function(error, co) {
      var subunits = topojson.feature(co, co.objects.mpios);
      var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
        .scale(1000)
        .translate([width / 2, height / 2])
        .center([-61,43])
        .rotate([2,3,2]);
    var path = d3.geo.path()
      .projection(projection);
    svg.append("path")
      .datum(subunits)
      .attr("d", path);
    svg.selectAll(".mpio")
        .data(topojson.feature(co, co.objects.mpios).features)
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("class", function(d) { return "mpio " + "_" + d.id; })
        .attr("d", path);
      svg.append("path")
      .datum(topojson.mesh(co, co.objects.mpios, function(a, b) { return a !== b; }))
      .attr("d", path)
      .attr("class", "mpio-borde");
      svg.append("path")
      .datum(topojson.mesh(co, co.objects.depts, function(a, b) { return a !== b; }))
      .attr("d", path)
      .attr("class", "depto-borde");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vstn1oaf/

Answer (score 0):

You can modify opacity, however, I assume you are doing this with `.attr("opacity",0)`. This will not work as you define the opacity in the css. CSS outranks `.attr`. Instead use `.style("opacity",0)`. There are multiple ways to achieve the effect though, such as `.style("stroke-width",0)`.

To show the entire mesh, not just the interior boundaries, you can use:

```
.datum(topojson.mesh(co, co.objects.depts))
```

Here is it all at work:

```js
var width = 900,
    height = 900;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

/* 
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON depts.json depto.shp -s_srs EPSG:26986 -t_srs EPSG:4326
topojson --id-property NOMBRE_DPT -p name=NOMBRE_DPT -p name -o colombia-departamentos.json depts.json
*/

d3.json("https://cdn.rawgit.com/finiterank/mapa-colombia-js/9ae3e4e6/colombia-municipios.json", function(error, co) {
    var subunits = topojson.feature(co, co.objects.mpios);
    var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
     .scale(2000)
     .translate([width / 2, height / 2])
     .center([-61,43])
     .rotate([2,3,2]);
 var path = d3.geo.path()
  .projection(projection);
 svg.append("path")
  .datum(subunits)
  .attr("d", path);
 svg.selectAll(".mpio")
     .data(topojson.feature(co, co.objects.mpios).features)
    .enter().append("path")
     .attr("class", function(d) { return "mpio " + "_" + d.id; })
     .attr("d", path);
    svg.append("path")
    .datum(topojson.mesh(co, co.objects.mpios, function(a, b) { return a !== b; }))
    .attr("d", path)
    .attr("class", "mpio-borde");
    svg.append("path")
    .datum(topojson.mesh(co, co.objects.depts))
    .attr("d", path)
    .attr("class", "depto-borde");
  /*    svg.selectAll(".dept-label")
  .data(topojson.feature(co, co.objects.depts).features)
   .enter().append("text")
    .attr("class", function(d) { return "dept-label " + d.id; })
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + path.centroid(d) + ")"; })
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function(d) { return d.properties.name; });*/
});

function fadeout() {
 d3.selectAll(".mpio")
    .transition()
    .style("opacity",0)
    .duration(1000);
}

function fadein() {
 d3.selectAll(".mpio")
    .transition()
    .style("opacity",1)
    .duration(1000);
}

function fatten() {
 d3.selectAll(".depto-borde")
    .transition()
    .style("stroke-width",2)
    .duration(1000);
}

function diet() {
 d3.selectAll(".depto-borde")
    .transition()
    .style("stroke-width",0)
    .duration(1000);
}

var show = true;

function showcase() {
 setTimeout(function() {
    show = !show;
  if (show) { fadein();fatten(); }
  else { fadeout(); diet(); }
  showcase();
 }, 1500)
}

showcase();
```

```css
/*.mpio._44279 { fill: #fff; }*/

path {
   fill: #777;
}

.mpio {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-opacity: .25;
  stroke-width: .5px;
  pointer-events: none;
}



.mpio-borde {
  opacity: 0;
  fill: none;
  stroke: #00ff00;
  __stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-width: 0.5;}
.depto-borde {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ff0000;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-width: 1;
  opacity: 1;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"> </script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, was the https:// for external library rather than http:// (guess I should always check with a couple browsers)